# Laravel React authentication

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, npm, react-dom

I'm new to react, what I'm trying to achieve is user login using react components in laravel.

https://github.com/000kelvin/laravel-react-authentication

I followed this and I installed everything.When I'm running this project I seem to get error regarding prop.
Terminal asked me to update **react** and **react-dom** that I already updated

**Laravel 5.8**; 
**npm 6.4.1**; 
**react@16.2.0**; 
**react-dom@16.2.1**

```
import LoginContainer from './LoginContainer';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirect: props.location,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <LoginContainer redirect={this.state.redirect} />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
export default withRouter(Login)
```

Router.js looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Login from "./views/Login/Login";
import Register from "./views/Register/Register";
import NotFound from "./views/NotFound/NotFound";

// User is LoggedIn
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./views/user/Dashboard/Dashboard"; 

const Main = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
       <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
);
export default Main;
```

Showing out this Error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to
>   'Route': the prop is not a valid React component
>       in Route (created by Testlog)
>       in Testlog
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for 
>    built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: > object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined > in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: there is a problem in your route code. Can you post that too ?

Comment: Edited my post, please check now! @kais

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
<Route path="/login"  component={props => <Login {...props} />}/>
```

in your routes

Comment: what does this {..props} means?

Comment: that is optional if you want to send any props to the component from route

Comment: Ok understood! Well that didn't work.I have another error let me post that also.

Comment: the problem is with your export component . Is `./views/Login/Login` is correct path .may be it is just `./views/Login`. try it .

Comment: No, its a directory in views the structure is like this I've shared the git url also, you can check complete code with structure there.